# How can I make a web page show the contents of a file even after I change the file?

Tags: javascript, batch-file, automation, wiki

Hey everyone I got a wiki question. We store files in *.7z in one server and have a wiki on another. I need to make a script that pulls the file names from one script and adds the code behind it so I can post it in the wiki. We do a ton of files a month and typing them all by hand won't cut it.

Here is what I need.

```
Var filename or string

For each file in the list {
Filename= File

    Write ('<br><file>SERVERNAME\C$\VideosArchive\ '+Filename+ '|' +Filename+ </file> <br/>)
```

So when the output comes out it has to look like.

```
<file>\\SERVERNAME\c$\VideoArchive\FILENAME.7z|FILENAME</file>
```

but i need something that auto generates that if that makes since.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
pushd \\servername\C$\VideosArchive
rem by the way, you should make that a share instead of using C$. Plays nicer with privileges and stuff
for %%f in (*) do (
  echo ^<br^>^<file^>SERVERNAME\C$\VideosArchive\%%~nxf^|%%~nxf^</file^>^</br^>
  rem do I need to ask why you are using "br" as if it had content? It's a tag without content ...
)
popd
```

Comment: its for the wiki we wrote the script today and the wiki script uses html in it for whatever reason in the tables. that script looks some what like what we wrote thanks.

Comment: Yeah, sorry; that was a misunderstanding on my part. The way how you use `br` there is just nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a very simple task.
You could create an app or PowerShell script to perform the dynamic creation of this file.